# How to get Powershell in VSCode or ISE to give the specific failing line

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm sure I must be missing something really basic but I've been revisiting Powershell of late to get up to speed with 7.1 and can't seem to get it to tell me where an error is thrown, either in VSCode or ISE.

[image: Error display]

In the above from VSCode (same report in ISE) the error isn't on that line, it's a couple of levels deeper in a function called by CompareFiles, but it always seems to report the caller of the caller of the code which has failed, rather than the actual failing line.

I've searched here, there and everywhere and found lots of clever tweaks and debugging ideas which I could add but I don't understand why it doesn't just give me the failing line here, rather than a line a level or two up in the call stack. It's as if the CompareFiles function has some kind of pragma that says "Dont record debugging info for me or anything I call" but it hasn't (and that probably doesn't exist anyway!).

I can't help feeling I've just not set some obvious debug setting, or set one incorrectly while I've been tinkering.

If it makes a difference, I'm calling a PS module from a PS Script, the module is loaded fine from the PSPath via Import-Module, and the line being reported is in the module, as is the actual failing line (both are in the same module), so it's not some problem where it's only debugging the script and not the module.

Both the script and the module have the below at the top;

`Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`

As I say, I get an identical error when I use the ISE so it's not a VSCode setting.

Debugging line by line works fine, so I can step through to find the failing line but surely it should just pop up and tell me.

[Later] I should not it's not just this error, it's been like that for days with all sorts of runtime errors with this and other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me - I simply removed..

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

..from the script and the module, this was essentially implementing the imaginary pragma I mentioned. I removed it and now get the failing error line.

I probably only need it at one of the two levels if anywhere but error handling works just fine without it, so have removed it everywhere, perhaps I'll look into what it does properly at some point.

Serves me right for adding something blindly because it sounded good, i.e. "Sure, I want it to stop when there's an error, why wouldn't I ? - I'll add that statement then" and not re-testing or looking further into it.